# Retrieve table data from another webpage using PHP

Tags: php, html, file-get-contents, preg-match-all, information-retrieval

**I want to retrieve some data that in a table format form that webpage i need in my webpage.**

**I follow many link and solution from stackoverflow but i can't get any data.**

**Below are the URL that data i want to retrieve:**
http://www.ip2location.com/demo/1.22.99.222

In the above URL one information table that data i want get.

Please anyone provide the code for retrieve data.

Thank you in advance.

Here are the code. I can't get any error from this code. Also can't get output of regex filter code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Welcome To MY Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="signform">
<?php
// Function to get the client ip address
echo "<br/>".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
echo "<br/>".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
echo "<br/>".$_SERVER['SERVER_SOFTWARE'];
echo "<br/>".$_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'];
echo "<br/>".$_SERVER['ALL_HTTP'];
echo "<br/>".$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']."<br/>";
// These lines are mandatory.
require_once 'Mobile_Detect.php';
$detect = new Mobile_Detect;

// Any mobile device (phones or tablets).
if ( $detect->isMobile() ) {
echo "Device Type : Mobile";

}
// Any tablet device.
else if( $detect->isTablet() ){
echo "Device Type : Tablet";
}
else {
echo "Device Type : PC";
}
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
echo $ip;
$content = file_get_contents("http://www.ip2location.com/demo/$ip");
preg_match_all('/<body>(.*?)<\/body>/s',$content,$output,PREG_SET_ORDER);
echo $output;
echo "<br/> ISP : ".$isp."<br/> City : ".$city."<br/> State : ".$state."<br/> Country : ".$country."<br/> zipcode : ".$zipcode;
?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here are the Screenshot of Output:

```
1.22.98.173
appstechsolution.in
Apache Phusion_Passenger/4.0.10 mod_bwlimited/1.4 mod_fcgid/2.3.9
HTTP/1.1
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/29.0.1547.76 Safari/537.36
Device Type : PC1.22.98.173Array
ISP : 
City : 
State : 
Country : 
zipcode :
```

Comment: Hi user2940072, welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the guide to asking questions: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask  What is the structure of your table?  What data do you want to get from it?  What code have you already written to get it?  What problem did you have?

Comment: **Hi S List**, Thank you for your suggestion and learn me for how to use stac koverflow. Now also please provide the solution.

Comment: That website offers a php module for you to download and use rather than trying to scrape the webpage: http://www.ip2location.com/developers/php

Comment: Thank you for suggestion of module. I already know that. If i use module to get data than i need database pack of 77 mb. It s very hard. Can help for get data using above metohd. Like get data from other page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [simpleHTMLDom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm) this will load destination web page and scrap needed table.

```
include_once('classes/simple_html_dom.php');
$html = file_get_html('http://www.ip2location.com/demo/1.22.99.222');
echo $html->find("#main-content .table", 0);
```